# Vivado/XSDK: How to access address from Zynq M_AXI_GP0 Bus?

Tags: c, fpga, xilinx, vivado, bare-metal

Let's say I built a vivado Zynq FPGA project, and I want to write and read the Zynq's "M_AXI_GP0" port from a c-program running on the zynq as follows.  Further, let's suppose the address I want to read and write on the "M_AXI_GP0" port of the Zynq is address "0x000A1000". How would I do that in the code below?  Do I need to worry about virtual address to physical address translation in the ARM?  is there a XIL api for that? etc... see code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "platform.h"


#include "xil_printf.h"

void write(uint32_t addr, uint32_t wdata) {
   //????? how to implement
}

uint32_t read(uint32_t addr) {
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    init_platform();

    print("Hello World\n\r");

    uint32_t beef;
    write(0x000A1000, 0xDEADBEEF);
    write(0x000A1004, 0x12345678);
    beef = read(0x000A1000);

    cleanup_platform();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Xilinx ZYNQ - ARM CORTEX A9 -Xilinx SDK]

Answer (score 0):

The "xil_ io.h" file contains the interface for the general IO component, which encapsulates the Input/Output functions for processors that do not require any special I/O handling:

```
u32  Xil_In32  (UINTPTR Addr);
void Xil_Out32 (UINTPTR Addr, u32 Value);
```

The "M_AXI_GP0" Bus is mapped to the PL or "Programmable Logic" address region in the Zynq Address Map:

```
Xilinx Zynq: ARM Cortex A9 Memory Map

DDR                    0x00000000 - 0x3FFFFFFF
PL                     0x40000000 - 0xBFFFFFFF
Reserved               0xC0000000 - 0xDFFFFFFF
Memory mapped devices  0xE0000000 - 0xE02FFFFF
Reserved               0xE0300000 - 0xE0FFFFFF
NAND, NOR              0xE1000000 - 0xE3FFFFFF
SRAM                   0xE4000000 - 0xE5FFFFFF
Reserved               0xE6000000 - 0xF7FFFFFF
AMBA APB Peripherals   0xF8000000 - 0xF8FFFFFF
Reserved               0xF9000000 - 0xFBFFFFFF
Linear QSPI - XIP      0xFC000000 - 0xFDFFFFFF
Reserved               0xFE000000 - 0xFFEFFFFF
OCM                    0xFFF00000 - 0xFFFFFFFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the AXI GPIO driver and example in [here](https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/tree/master/XilinxProcessorIPLib/drivers/gpio)?  Whether you need to worry about virtual to physical address translation depends on what exactly are you running? Do you have a bare metal/RTOS setup?